# msg.sender is different from chosen account in Metamask when checking from constructor

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I am trying to do a comparison of msg.sender and another address inside a contract constructor. The problem is that in the constructor, msg.sender is a different address from the one I chose in Metamask.

```
constructor() public {
        emit constructorInit(msg.sender); // for debugging
        if(msg.sender == issuer) { // fails
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Address chosen through Metamask: 0x08947c98C28054e1D1B17F8351F880aF8f5ba0eC

Value of msg.sender(obtained from event): 0x72f29a5fb7cca78d79370737561dce9c1d73a4ce

However, `web3.eth.getCoinbase()` does return the expected address 0x08947c98C28054e1D1B17F8351F880aF8f5ba0eC

On Metamask, it's connected localhost 7545 which corresponds to the server on Ganache/Truffle.

web3 version: 1.2.4
solidity version: 0.5.12;

Comment: How Metamask is configured? Is it connected to a private network? How is the contract deployed? How is web3 connected to MetaMask? Which version of web3 are you using?

Comment: When this constructor() is invoked? Is it while migrating contract? If you are using truffle to migrate, it considers 1st wallet address for migration. Did you check whether the  value of msg.sender is other wallet address?